# Handle event Power button press if activity is Closed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, key-events

How can I know if the Power button is Pressed while Activity is Closed, not screen on/off because I want to know exactly how many times Power button is Pressed.

I think I have use Broadcast or Service, but I can't find any solutions that work for me, I don't know what should I do. Here are some solutions I found but not work.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        // Do something here...
        Log.d("#tag", "ACTION_Down ");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

Manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />
```

or this, but I don't need it because It work only screen on/off, if I fast double click Power button when screen Off then It not work.

```
public class PowerBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private boolean screenOff;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
        {
            screenOff = true;
            Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_SCREEN_OFF ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("#tag", "ACTION_SCREEN_OFF ");
        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
        {
            screenOff = false;
            Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_SCREEN_ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("#tag", "ACTION_SCREEN_On ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

check this out :

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
                Log.i("", "Dispath event power");
                //do watever u want.
                return true;
        }

        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

or try the hole code :

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.userpresent"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.userpresent.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

            <service android:name="com.example.userpresent.LockService" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.userpresent;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockService.class));


   }
}
```

LockService.java

```
package com.example.userpresent;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class LockService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
LockService getService() {
return LockService.this;
}
}
}
```

ScreenReceiver.java

```
package com.example.userpresent;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    Log.e("LOB","onReceive");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // do whatever you need to do here
            wasScreenOn = false;
            Log.e("LOB","wasScreenOn"+wasScreenOn);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // and do whatever you need to do here
            wasScreenOn = true;

        }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){
            Log.e("LOB","userpresent");
            Log.e("LOB","wasScreenOn"+wasScreenOn);
            //do something.
        }
    }
}
```